# C# how to stop a async task on button click

Tags: c#, task

I just discovered the `async` keyword in C# and just wondering how to stop it using a button click. I just want to understand how it works and how to stop the task after you execute another event. I tried stop it using bool but had no luck. Below is my code:

```
//start
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Read(true);
}

private async void Read(bool state)
{
    while (state == true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Read 1");
    }
}

//stop
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Read(false);
}
```

Comment: you can use [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Some more good reading here: [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken;

//start
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancellationToken= new CancellationTokenSource();
    Read();
}



private async void Read()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
       listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Read 1");
    }, cancellationToken.Token);
}


//stop
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cancellationToken!= null) 
    cancellationToken.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Its says `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression.`

Comment: Sorry, updated! Probably you will need to find another way to simulate the delay

Answer (score 0):

i think if you want the thread to be stopped in some cases 
you may do these

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;

    Read(ct);
}



private async void Read( CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
           Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
}
```

Comment: So how do you cancel it?